# [Node JS]How to install 'ffi' and 'ref' modules on windows 10

Tags: node.js, ref, node-gyp, node-ffi

When I run:

```
npm install ffi
```

or

```
npm install ref
```

I got an [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv2ma.png)

I installed node-gyp, python 2.7.11 and Visual studio build tools.

Anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install latest version of npm by running the following command

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```